# Create function with specific prototype

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What is the best way to create a function with a specified object as prototype in Javascript? For ordinary objects, you can just use `Object.create()`. However, this obviously won't create a function. So far, the only way I've found is to define a function normally and then call `Object.setPrototypeOf()`, but `setPrototypeOf` is considered to be evil and bad for performance. Is there any alternative?

Comment: _`setPrototypeOf` is considered to be evil and bad for performance_. What?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Just look at the scary warnings on MDN for instance

Comment: Are you trying to create a constructor function that creates objects with a certain prototype, or are you trying to set the prototype of the function itself? (if it's option 2, why would you need to do that?)

Comment: Yes, the later.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this? I can't think of any benefits to giving a function a different prototype, but it does have downsides in that you'd lose the normal function prototype's `.bind()`, `.call()`, etc. methods. If you feel you *must* do this, just use `Object.setPrototypeOf()`, which may not be great for performance but certainly isn't "evil".

Comment: The main motivation is that it is the only way to inherit static properties when simulating subclasses without es6 classes.